# What does this nm output "V typeinfo name for void*" mean?

Tags: c++, linux, nm

Could you please tell me what do these pieces of nm's output mean?

> $nm --demangle --dynamic --defined-only --extern-only lib.so
>
> 0000000000238ba0 V typeinfo name for void*
>
> 0000000000238b80 V typeinfo for void*

What are the C++ constructs they are generated for?

I've searched the Internet but didn't find the explanation.

Comment: Welcome you to StackOverflow, Please take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of giving the obvious answer, that's just the data needed for `typeinfo(void*)`. What else would it be?